# Dynamically change the text of TextView from Spinner

Tags: android

I am new to Android.
How can I dynamically change the text of `TextView` when I select any item from `Spinner`.

Regards.

The code i am using

```
    private Spinner paidIn = null;  
     paidIn = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.paidIn);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                 this, R.array.currencies, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
         adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
         paidIn.setAdapter(adapter);  


     paidIn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) 
                    {
                        setStrTypeExpense(); // my Function, i want to call to change Textview
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this code

```
mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) 
    {
         textView.setText(mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Giving error, the method setOnItemSelectedListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) in the type AdapterView<SpinnerAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments (new OnItemSelectedListener(){})

Comment: if u r using custom adapter then use arg2 as index to ur array data and get that string.